# How to add a list under form in my module page?

Tags: theming, 8, forms

I have created a Drupal 8 module and I need help to put list under form. Below is my code:

Controller

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\bocExtractor\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Html;
use Drupal\Core\StreamWrapper\PublicStream;

class BocExtractorController extends ControllerBase {

    public function DisplayBocExtractorSettingsForm() {
        $output = array();
        $form_class = '\Drupal\bocExtractor\Form\BocExtractorSettingsForm';
        $build['form'] = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form_class);
        $build['#title'] = t('Boc Extractor Settings');
        $build['list'] = array(
            '#weight' => 1,
            '#markup' => $this->BOCsList(),
        );

        return $build;
    }


    public function BOCsList() {

        ?>

        <div class="wrap">

            <div class="list-bocs">

                <h1>List of files / Liste des fichiers:</h1>

                <ul>

                <?php

                    if(!isset($_GET['start'])) {  
                        $start = 0;  
                    } else {  
                        $start = $_GET['start'];  
                    }  

                    $exclude_files = array("");  
                    $ifiles = Array();  
                    $handle = opendir(DRUPAL_ROOT . "/" . PublicStream::basePath() . "/bocs/");  
                    $number_to_display = '9';

                    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {  
                       if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && !in_array($file, $exclude_files)) {    
                           $ifiles[] = $file;  
                       }  
                    }  

                    closedir($handle);  

                    $total_files = count($ifiles);  
                    $req_pages = ceil($total_files/$number_to_display);  

                    // echo "Nombre total = ". $total_files."<br>";  

                    for($z=0; $z<$number_to_display; $z++) { 
                        if ($start < 0)
                            $start = 0;
                        $vf = $z + $start;  
                        $ifiles_display = explode(".", $ifiles[$vf]);  
                        echo "<li class='item-boc'><a class='btn-boc' href=". $ifiles[$vf]. ">".  $ifiles_display[0] . "</a></li>";  
                        echo '<br>';  
                    }  

                    // echo "<br> Pagination = ". $req_pages. "<br>";  
                    echo "<a href=\"?start=0\">Premier</a> |";  

                    for( $x=1; $x<$req_pages; $x++ ) { ?>  
                        <a href="?page=parametres-wp-boc&start=<? echo ($x-1)*$number_to_display; ?>"><? echo $x; ?></a> |  

                        <? } ?>  
                        <a href="?page=parametres-wp-boc&start=<? echo $total_files-$number_to_display; ?>">Dernier</a> |

                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>

    <?php }

 }
```

Form code

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\bocExtractor\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class BocExtractorSettingsForm extends ConfigFormBase {

    /** 
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function getFormId() {
        return 'bocExtractor_admin_settings';
    }

    /** 
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    protected function getEditableConfigNames() {
        return [
          'bocExtractor.settings',
        ];
    }

    /** 
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $config = $this->config('bocExtractor.settings');

        $form['Description'] = array(
            '#prefix' => $this->t('Personnalisez le lien de publications et les classes CSS des BOCs au cas la BRVM changeait de site.'),
        ); 

        $form['BocExtractor_url'] = array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => $this->t('BOCs url'),
          '#default_value' => $config->get('BocExtractor_url'),
        );  

        $form['BocExtractor_class'] = array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => $this->t('BOCs class'),
          '#default_value' => $config->get('BocExtractor_class'),
        );  

        return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
    }
 }
```

Routing:

```
bocExtractor.routing:
  path: '/admin/structure/bocextractor'
  defaults:
    _title: 'boc Extractor'
    _controller: '\Drupal\bocExtractor\Controller\BocExtractorController::DisplayBocExtractorSettingsForm'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access administration pages'
```

I get list on top and my form on bottom. See this screenshot: http://prntscr.com/e1459i

How can I get what I want?

Comment: Hi @Cutis, welcome to Drupal Answers. To improve your question, could you paste the code instead of linking to a printscreen? It is also advised to upload the screenshot and display it inline.

Comment: I have added my code.

Comment: You can't write code like that in a method, that can not possibly work. It is going to print our HTML while executing that code. You need to put it in a string and *return* it. And as commented by @timmillwood, you should instead define a twig temple and put the HTML in there.

Comment: Ok I understand. but please can someone show me how I can put my list code into twig template and how I can call it? I tried but I get nothing, just form.

Answer (score 0):

```
$form['list'] = [
  '#markup' => $this->myList(),
];
```

Put this in your form. No need for the controller, update the routing to go directly to the form class.

Also don't put HTML in your PHP, use a twig template file.
Don't use `$_GET` either.

Comment: I have already tried this. I have a same result. Nothing has changed

Comment: I think the issue you see in the screenshot is because of the `?>` in the code. Don't do this. Add HTML via a twig template.